# Extract/Insert element at index from value - LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Is there a way to extract or insert an element at an index from a value instead of an int? I would like to be able to use something like `ExtractElementInst` but for arrays instead of vectors.

Right now I am doing

```
mBuilder.CreateExtractValue(refArray, index)
```

But, I need to be able to pass it a `Value *` because I would like to be able to access array elements at the index of the value of a variable. For example:

```
array[i]
```

With the above code, I am limited to:

```
array[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform address arithmetic with arbitrary, non-constant indices, you need to use the `getelementptr` instruction, which is created using the `CreateGEP` function.

Note that `getelementptr` needs its argument to be a pointer, so you'll want to directly use the global variable or `alloca` that holds the array, rather than reading it first. This also means that you need a zero as the first index to follow the pointer. So all in all, the generated code to read `array[i]` should look something like this:

```
@array = global [3 x i32] [1,2,3]

define void f() {
  %i = ; calculuate the index here
  %array_i_ptr = getelementptr [3 x i32], [3 x i32]* @array, i32 0, i32 %i
  %array_i_value = load i32, i32* array_i_ptr
  ; do something with %array_i_value
  ret
}
```

Here I assumed `array` was a global variable. For a local variable, you'd use `alloca` instead. For a dynamically allocated array, you'd have a call to `malloc`, no array types and a `getelementptr` instruction with only one index (because we'd be working with a pointer to int, rather than pointer to array to int, so the zero index isn't necessary).

Comment: Thanks for another helpful answer - this works perfectly. I am a little surprised that there is not a more straight forward way to do this though.

Comment: Also, Is there an equivalent of `CreateGEP` for inserting values?

Comment: @pudility The GEP doesn't change, you just use `store` instead of `load`.

Comment: @pudility Basically the GEP gives you the address of an array element (or struct member if you use GEP on structs). You can then read and write that element using `load` and `store` just as you would a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. I cannot even fathom how much time and effort must have gone into creating LLVM.